# Discord.js 18 - How to get an user's join date in a specific guild?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I already know how to get an user's account creation, but how do I get when he joined a guild?

Here's my current code for my command: I'm using force fetch to get the user's info.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, Client, GatewayIntentBits, PermissionFlagsBits } = require('discord.js');
const {createFooter, userAvatar, creationDateTimestamp} = require('../../utility');
const {token} = require('../../config.json');
const client = new Client({ 
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds],
});

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('user')
        .setDescription('Provides information about the user.')
        .addUserOption(option =>
            option
                .setName('user')
                .setDescription('Select a user to view')),
    async execute(interaction) { // Currently only works with a single user at a time...
        client.login(token); // Must log in
        let targetUser = interaction.options.getUser('user') ?? interaction.user;
        const user = await client.users.fetch(targetUser.id); // Force fetch
        let accentColor = user.hexAccentColor;
        if (user.hexAccentColor != null && user.hexAccentColor != undefined)    
            user.hexAccentColor = 0xffffff;
        const userEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor(user.hexAccentColor)
            .setTitle(user.displayName)
            .setDescription(user.username)
            //.setThumbnail(userAvatar(interaction.user))
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Creation date', value: `${creationDateTimestamp(user)}` },
            )
            .setThumbnail(userAvatar(user))
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(createFooter(interaction.user));
        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [userEmbed] });
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the user is in the guild then you should be able to get that information in the [`joinedAt`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=joinedAt) property of the [`GuildMember`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMember) class. This will return the time the user joined the guild as a [Javascript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

To get the GuildMember class of the target user:

```js
const guildMember = await guild.members.fetch(targetUser.id);
```

Then to get the time they joined at:

```js
const userJoinTime = guildMember.joinedAt
```

If you wish to get the value of the `joinedAt` property as a numerical timestamp you use the [`joinedTimestamp`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=joinedTimestamp) property, like so:

```js
const userJoinTime = guildMember.joinedTimestamp
```

Comment: `User`s don't have `joinedAt` properties. You mention and link to `GuildMember`s but use a `User`. You should fix that.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros My bad! Done!

Comment: Thank you so much! You have to be logged in to force fetch members right?

Comment: @AlistairManicardi You don't need to be logged in as a user to fetch members. So long as your bot has a valid bot token and is in the guild you are trying to fetch from you should be fine.